# Linux. Which dll contains execv?

Tags: linux, mono, pinvoke

I need to call this procedure through PInvoke in the mono application.
Just name of library please.

Comment: I'd expect this to vary from system to system. I think you need to reconsider your approach.

Comment: My approach excellent.

Comment: Linux has no DLLs, it has shared objects. The one you want is the standard C library, `libc.so`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being part of the GNU C lib it is in `libc`:

> http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace posix
{
    class MainClass
    {
        [DllImport ("libc", SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern int system (string exec);

        [DllImport ("libc", SetLastError=true)]
        public static extern int execv (string path, string[] argv);

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Error:{0}", system ("ls -l"));
            Console.WriteLine ("Error:{0}", execv ("/usr/bin/vi", new string[] { "/usr/bin/vi" , "foobar.txt" }));
            // Of course, being execv without failure we never come back...
            Console.WriteLine ("Should never be displayed");
            Console.WriteLine ("Error:{0}", Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.execv ("/usr/bin/ls", new string[] { "/usr/bin/ls" }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error found. You must duplicate program name as first argument, for example:  `execv("nano",new string[]{"nano"});`

Comment: Your are correct, updated it, happens when you type code from memory...S.O. needs an inline C# compiler/debugger;-)